# Open and close a dialog many times with Primefaces DialogFramework

Tags: jsf, primefaces, dialog

i have a problem using the Dialog Framework of Primefaces.
(WildFly 8.2, Primefaces 5.3.12, Java 8, Eclipse 4.3.2, Ubuntu 14.04, Firefox/Chrome)

If i open a dialog with :

```
 RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().openDialog(...);
```

and then close it with :

```
RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().closeDialog(null);
```

The dialog is closed, but now if i try to open it again, nothing happen. 
If i look in the Firefox console i can see a JavaScript error just after le dialog is closed :

```
TypeError: dlgWidget is undefined
PrimeFaces.dialog.DialogHandler.closeDialog()
primefaces.js.xhtml:6
b.closeDialog()
primefaces.js.xhtml:1
<anonyme>
jquery.js.xhtml:1
.globalEval/<()
jquery.js.xhtml:14
.globalEval()
jquery.js.xhtml:14
PrimeFaces.ajax.ResponseProcessor.doEval()
primefaces.js.xhtml:3
PrimeFaces.ajax.Response.handle()
primefaces.js.xhtml:3
PrimeFaces.ajax.Request.send/q.success()
primefaces.js.xhtml:3
bH.Callbacks/i()
jquery.js.xhtml:25
bH.Callbacks/cc.fireWith()
jquery.js.xhtml:25
cf()
jquery.js.xhtml:25
.send/i()
jquery.js.xhtml:25
primefaces.js.xhtml:6:3190
```

in the primefaces.js this seems to be this code :

```
closeDialog : function(cfg) {
    var rootWindow = this.findRootWindow(), 
    dlgs = $(rootWindow.document.body).children('div.ui-dialog[data-pfdlgcid="' + cfg.pfdlgcid + '"]').not("[data-queuedforremoval]"),
    dlgsLength = dlgs.length, 
    dlg = dlgs.eq(dlgsLength - 1), 
    parentDlg = dlgsLength > 1 ? dlgs.eq(dlgsLength - 2) : null, 
    dlgWidget = rootWindow.PF(dlg.data("widgetvar")), 
    sourceWidgetVar = dlgWidget.cfg.sourceWidgetVar,
 ....
```

I've 2 different behaviors :

- When i work in Eclipse, there is no error (i can open/close the dialog many times without any problem)
- When my software is compiled and deployed (WAR in an EAR) i've got the problem with the Dialog Framework. If i close the dialog with the cross on the right top (not my commandButton) there is no problem.

Do you have any ideas about what is going wrong when it's deployed ?
Thank you for your help.

Managed bean

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped  
public class FamilleArticlesController { 

public void actFermerDialog(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
    RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().closeDialog(null);
}

public void actDialogTypes(ActionEvent actionEvent) {

    Map<String,Object> options = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    options.put("modal", true);
    options.put("draggable", true);
    options.put("resizable", false);
    options.put("contentHeight", 320);

    Map<String,List<String>> params = new HashMap<String,List<String>>();
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    list.add(modeEcran.modeString(EnumModeObjet.C_MO_INSERTION));
    params.put("modeEcranDefaut", list);

    RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().openDialog("articles/dialog_type_famille_article", options, params);

}

public void handleReturnDialogTypes(SelectEvent event) {
    if(event!=null && event.getObject()!=null) {
    }   
}
}
```

Dialog template : dialog_type_famille_article.xhtml

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

<h:head>
    <title>Type famille d'Article</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        .ui-widget {
            font-size: 90%;
        }
    </style>
</h:head>

<h:body>
    <h:form id="idDialogFamilleArticle">    
        <ui:include src="famille_articles.xhtml"/>
    </h:form>
</h:body>
</html>
```

Dialogue include : famille_articles.xhtml

```
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

<p:panel id="familleDataTableF" class="mt30 bg-grey">


        <p:commandButton id="idInsererFamilleArticle" value="Ajouter" title="Insérer" process="@this"
        update=":form:tabView,:form:messages,:form" 
            actionListener="#{familleArticlesController.actDialogTypes}"
            styleClass="icon-insert icon" >
            <p:ajax event="dialogReturn" listener="#{familleArticlesController.handleReturnDialogTypes}" 
                update=":form"/>
        </p:commandButton>
 </p:panel>

 <p:panel>
<p:commandButton id="familleArticlesAnnulerDialogue" 
value="Annuler"
    styleClass="btn-cancel btn" process="@this"
    disabled="#{familleArticlesAnnulerController.etatBouton('annuler')}"
    actionListener="#{familleArticlesController.actFermerDialog}"
    rendered="#{dansDialogue != null ? true : false}" />

</p:panel>
 </ui:composition>
```

Comment: I don't know exactly why but my problem was maven put a version of the primefaces.jar in the lib directory of my EAR. Removing the dependency that take primefaces.jar in the lib directory solved my problem.